# If $Z$ is standard normal, and $Z^2$ is chi-squared, is $Z/(\sqrt{Z^2/n})$ a t distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

If $Z$ is $\mathcal N(0, 1)$, and $Z^2$ is $\chi^2_1$, is $\frac Z {\sqrt{Z^2/n}}$ a $t$ distribution with $n=1$ degree of freedom?

Comment: I believe you have an error in your question (since, specifics of the question aside) one would expect the denominator to be the square root of a chi-square on its df ($\sqrt{Z^2/n}$). By taking $\sqrt Z$ you have a 50% chance of taking the square root of a negative number; I doubt that's the intent. Is this for some subject?

Comment: Can you say something about where this question is coming from? It doesn't make much sense to me. It looks like a homework problem, but it is confused, so (hopefully) no one creating &/or assigning HW problems would actually ask this. Eg, in addition to @Glen_b's point above, if $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, then $Z^2$ *must* be $\chi^2_1$.

Comment: My apologies, I meant that the bottom was $Z^2$ instead of $Z$. Meaning, $Z^2$ from $Z~N(0,1)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: modifying to fit with changes to Q.

The answer is *still* no.

Note that if $n=1$ we can just drop $n$.

If we try calculating $Z/\sqrt{Z^2}$ for a few values of $Z$, what do we find?

Let's try 0.5, 3 and -1.

We get $0.5/\sqrt{0.5^2} = 1$ and $3/\sqrt{3^2} = 1$ and $-1/\sqrt{(-1)^2} = -1$.

In fact it's always either 1 or -1, except when $Z=0$ (an event of probability 0).

We can also see that algebraically:

$\sqrt{Z^2}=|Z|$ and $Z = \text{sign}(Z).|Z|$

Hence $Z/\sqrt{Z^2} = \text{sign}(Z)$ (except at Z=0).

That has, as you suggested in comments, a distribution which has 50% probability of being 1 and 50% probability of being -1. Since a $t_1$ distribution *doesn't* give a 50% probability of being each of those values, the original statistic doesn't have a $t_1$ distribution.

Comment: My apologies, that is the correct form!

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Comment: I was reading through an old textbook from the 1950s and found this example as a way of showing what was and what wasn't a t-distribution. Unfortunately, the textbook didn't come with any solutions.

Comment: Interesting. That makes it definitely a self-study question. Please add the tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). With that in mind, what have you tried?

Comment: Please note that my answer updated.

Comment: I believe that $Z$ and $Z^2$ are not independent since $Z^2$ is generated from $Z$. Is that why?

Comment: Obviously they're not independent. If you know Z, you certainly know Z^2, that's perfect dependence. But that doesn't tell you it's *not* t, only that you haven't satisfied a condition that you know would give a t. (There should be a perfectly dependent quantity that will give a t \*\*.) ... try addressing the question at the end of my answer; what are the possible outcomes of $Z/\sqrt{Z^2}$?  (\*\* actually I just realized what that perfectly dependent quantity must be, though of course it won't be distributed as chi-square)

Comment: The possible outcomes will be 1 and -1, each should have probability of 0.5 of occurring. It seems that since I cannot have all values, then would this nullify it being a t-distribution? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have it. I will incorporate your understanding into my answer.

Comment: Just a clarification if I may, I know from standard distribution theory that the random variable on top and the one in the square root must be independent. Why is it the case that being dependent doesnt destroy the argument that it is a t-distribution? Thanks!

Comment: The argument goes "If they're independent, the statistic is distributed $t$", which is of the form "If A then B". You're asking why it's the case "why isn't it necessarily the case that if not-A then not-B?". Consider "If it rained, the ground will be wet". Now I tell you "It didn't rain". Can you be certain the ground is dry? No, it doesn't follow, since there may be other ways for the ground to be wet. Essentially, the proof that you get a t-distribution didn't on its own establish the conditions for an if-and-only-if (or maybe it did - depending on what we're looking at and what you know)

Comment: Note that going from "if A then B" to "if not-A then not-B" is generally speaking a formal fallacy called ['*denying the antecedent*'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent). You need some additional knowledge to be able to conclude one from the other.